# JavaFX onMouseClickedEvent on ImageView

Tags: javafx

I have an ImageView with an Image inside it and when the image is clicked, a MouseClicked event should be triggered. However, the application is not even printing the test line.

```
Image cancel = new Image("/cancel.svg.png", 15, 15, false, false);
ImageView view = new ImageView(cancel);
view.setPickOnBounds(true);

view.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        /** execute code **/
    }
});
```

Complete version:
I have a ListView called "found_tags_list" and every cell inside that ListView should be a new class called: "ButtonListCell". I did this to add extra content to the cells based on some statements.

```
found_tags_list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell call(ListView<String> param) {
         return new ButtonListCell();
    }
});
```

Entire Cell class:

```
class ButtonListCell extends ListCell<String> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String obj, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(obj, empty);

        if (obj == null || obj.isEmpty() || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(obj);
            if (valid_tags.indexOf(obj) >= 0) {
                setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                Image cancel = new Image("/cancel.png", 15, 15, false, false);
                ImageView view = new ImageView(cancel);
                view.setPickOnBounds(true);

                view.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                         System.out.println("hi");
                         String item = getItem();
                         found_tags_list.getItems().remove(item);

                         for (Tag tag : rfidset) {
                             if (tag.getId().equals(item)) {
                                 rfidset.remove(tag);
                                 return;
                             }
                         }
                    }
                });

                setGraphic(view);
                setTextFill(Color.RED);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]? I've never encountered such an issue. Probably the node is covered by some other node or some ancestor is set to mouse transparent...

Comment: @fabian after some research I think I know what I do wrong: I think that the ImageView is not clickable because it is inside a ListView/Cell, might that be true?